# How to get current URL in Ruby/Rails in my plugin's module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, request

I need to get url info in my plugin's module.

request.request_uri is unavailable.

Has ruby/rails an analog of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as php?

For example:

```
module MyPlugin
  module Routing
    def self.getOpts
      # HIRE I NEED TO ANALYZE URL and return hash with resulting param
      return {controller: :divisions, action: :show, id: 11, as: :current}
    end
  end
end

# extend routing
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper
    def my_rout
      match 'articles', MyPlugin::Routing.getOpts
    end
  end
end

# In config/routes.rb
Rails::application.routes.draw do
  my_rout
end
```

That's what I need for example:

1. We get an url http://mysite.ru/slug_division_1/slug_division_2
2. division with id 2 have in DB table a field 'handler' with value 'any_controller#any_action'
3. In MyPlugin::Routing i'm doing analyze the url path and get from DB the value 'any_controller#any_action'
4. MyPlugin::Routing.getOpts return params {controller: :any_controller, action: :any_action, id: 2, as: :current}
5. From ActionDispatch::Routing.Mapper.my_rout we set new rout like this

   match 'slug_division_1/slug_division_2', {controller: :any_controller, action: :any_action, id: 2, as: :current}

Just a little hack.

Comment: say what? you want an answer in `ruby` or `php`?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the subject matter in comparison ruby and php

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve with the shown code? Like @daemin i have the feeling you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to make the `request_uri` a global variable in rails?

1) Add to folder 'vendor/plugins/myplugin/lib/myplugin' file `request_global.rb` with folowing code:

```
module Rack
  class MethodOverrideWithParams < Rack::MethodOverride
    def call(env)
        $request = Rack::Request.new(env) # $request is global vriable
        super(env)
    end
  end
end
```

2) In `vendor/plugins/myplugin/lib/myplugin.rb` add:

```
require 'myplugin/request_global'
```

3) In `config/application.rb` add:

```
config.middleware.swap 'Rack::MethodOverride', 'Rack::MethodOverrideWithParams'
```

4) Voilà, `$request` is now available from anywhere point the Rails application!

In my case it's useless because doing every time a database query for each `$request` to get the handler need to reload the routes (`Rails::Application.reload_routes!`). It degrades the performance. Defining all possible routes is more profitable even if these routes a few thousand. Reload the routes occurs only if someone edited the divisions.

Comment: Also global variables are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using `request.request_uri`.

Answer (score 0):

request.request_uri is the way to find the information you want. If you don't have access to it then you need to add a parameter to your function and call it from some place that does have access.

From memory Controllers do have access to the request_uri.

---

I think what you actually want is just one controller/action route in your table that accepts any paths, and in the controller action do the lookup and call the relevant function. Check out path globbing (using the '*' character in Rails 2.3, not sure if you're using Rails 3), and see if that fits what you are doing.

Then what you'll have is a single route that takes a long path, the controller and action breaks that path up into its own parts, performs the lookup, and calls the appropriate function (or other controller/action).

However I have to say a few words about a few things that I think you're doing wrong.

Unless you're doing something very tricky and quite out of the ordinary, don't store the controller and action in the database. That's what the ruby routes are for themselves. If you need to store these in a database then it sounds to me like you're doing it wrong.

You shouldn't hard code an id number into a route, let that be a variable that gets set. So instead of hard coding /some/thing/23 to match 'some/thing/23', instead make the route match 'some/thing/:id', and you'll get :id => 23 automatically.

Comment: how to do this? I tried extend ActionController::Base but not work

Comment: Looking at the code that you have there, I get the funny feeling that "you're doing it wrong". It seems to me that you're trying to create your own routing mechanism, when there's a suitable one within Rails already.

Comment: If use '*' then will be a single rout with redirects, it is not suitable.

Comment: About the things that you think me doing wrong. The question is not about what is right or wrong. I understand that I do. I have a problem that I have to do.

Comment: How Rails works with url, what classes it uses? I have a second day trying to understand out what's what :(

Comment: Ok there are a few things that I need to know: Why you are using a database to store routes in? Is there going to be any number of slugs, or just a maximum of 2? Why are you writing this as a plugin instead of just modifying the Rails site itself?

Comment: I'm trying made portal CMS on ROR. There are tree divisions with unlimited nesting in admin part of CMS. Each division has its own slug and handler (controller#action). If the handler empty then handler = 'divisions#show'. From the plugin I make gem. Now the only problem is how to get the url to analyze in front face CMS.

Comment: Well then the easiest way would be to create routes for the controllers and actions that you've created, and then have a glob '\*' route at the end for the case when nothing matches. Just because the url is '/foo/bar' doesn't mean you have to have a 'foo' controller with a 'bar' action. 

Now if you really want to have your routes and controllers matched by the database, you just need to create one glob '\*' route and inside of that function check the database, then call the appropriate function directly.

Comment: @Artem Add the answer then, as I'm curious to what it actually is.